# How to store a value from JTextField and using it with Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, actionlistener, runnable

I'm trying to do a simple program of a simple GUI where you have to put a number in a JTextField and press a JButton and the number that the user entered will generate new JTextFields inside the GUI. I'm facing a problem with "AWT-EventQueue-0". I have read about it a lot but none has helped me!

**My Code:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test2 extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener{
    private JTextField txtThread;
    private JButton btn1;
    private JTextField [] bookSeat;
    private String name;
    public int numFirst;

    public Test2() {

            //Setting the layout.
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            txtThread = new JTextField(); //"Number of threads"
            txtThread.setColumns(5);
            add(txtThread);


            btn1 = new JButton("Create threads");
            add(btn1);

            btn1.addActionListener(this);

            setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(false);
    }

    //A method for creating a number of threads depending on the user wish.
    public void createSeat() {

            numFirst = Integer.parseInt(txtThread.getText().trim());

            bookSeat = new JTextField[numFirst];

            name = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            //for loop for adding the new JTextFields into the GUI.
            for(int i = 0; i < numFirst; i++) {
                bookSeat[i] = new JTextField("Thread " + name);
                bookSeat[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                bookSeat[i].setEditable(false);
                add(bookSeat[i]);
                setVisible(true);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(btn1)) {
            createSeat();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Test2 gui = new Test2();

        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < gui.numFirst; i++) {
                Thread a = new Thread(gui, "" + i);
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                a.start();
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

My problem is in the main method specifically inside the for loop condition.

> *for(int i = 0; i < gui.numFirst; i++)*
>
> ***gui.numFirst***  is always giving me as 0. I tried in multiple ways to store the value that I'm entering in the JTextField but I couldn't.

Comment: 1) Swing is NOT thread safe; 2) Swing is single thread.  What does this mean? You should never call any UI related functionality from off the Event Dispatching Thread and you should never perform any blocking operations from within the EDT.  3) Swing is event driven.  This means that something happens and then you respond to it.  Things don't run in a linear flow

Comment: Ok, so you problem is, `createSet` is been called inside the context of the EDT (ie `Thread AWT-EventQueue-0`).  To be honest, your `for(int i = 0; i < gui.numFirst; i++)` is useless and pointless, as by the time you inspect the value of `numFirst` the user hasn't entered anything (remember the comment about "event driven")

Comment: So how would I store the entered value from JTextField and use it in the for loop? Because I still need that number to determine the number of Threads that I want to create.

Comment: Do it when the number becomes know - as a consequence of the `actionPerformed`